# why doesn't this regex (\d)\d\1 work to find alternate repetitive numbers from a string?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have to write regex to find all the repetitive alternate numbers from a given string.

For example:

552523
(5,5)and(2,2) are the pairs

My basic understanding of regex is not very good.
From what I understand the expression `(\d)\d\1` should give 525 and 252 but it only returns 5 while using `re.findall` function in python.

Why doesn't this work? And is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Oh,thanks.Do you know a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the overlapping match by using the `lookahead assertion`.
Would you please try the following:

```
import re
str = "552523"
m = re.finditer(r'(?=((\d)\d\2))', str)
for i in m:
    print(i.group(1))
```

Output:

```
525
252
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to come at it would be to `zip` over the string and a slice of the string offset by 2 looking for matching digits in the resulting tuples.

Example:

```
digit_string = "552523"

digit_pairs = [
    (x, y)
    for x, y in zip(digit_string, digit_string[2:])
    if x.isdigit() and y.isdigit() and x == y
]

print(digit_pairs)
```

Output:

```
[('5', '5'), ('2', '2')]
```

Comment: very nice solution though I was hoping to solve it using just regex. Other answer mentioned it.